# Azure event hub sending duplicate events

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am using azure event hub to receive notification on arrival of messages in inbox.

When I send an email without attachment I receive only one notification from event hub.

When I send an email with attachment I receive two notifications.

I have activated "Defender with Safe Attachments Dynamic Delivery" for my azure tenant.

Please advise me why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

How did you register that? Are you using Event Hub or Event grid? You can't register the Event Hub direct to listen to Exchange\Outlook. You need either event grid or something to tap into the Graph Api, listen to events like email sending and send it to Azure Event hub

Also when a message has an attachment, to get both message body and attachment, it will invoke Graph API twice:

1 for the body: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
and
1 for the attachments: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/%7Bid%7D/attachments)

Comment: I have registered on event hub to receive the notifiations.

Comment: I am consuming the events from multiple replicas, do you think there could be a race condition or single event getting consumed twice and that is why I am getting duplicates?